# MailKit search query problems

Tags: server, imap, mailkit

I use MailKit and IMAP Client. There are no problems with GMail mails, but when I make the same request to another server, problems appear.
Even a simple Search with the criterion MailKit.Search.SearchQuery.NotSeen does not work. I have access to the mailbox and mails are read, but filters do not work.
The only working filter is MailKit.Search.SearchQuery.All. Also I cannot change flag from NotSeen to Seen using Inbox.AddFlags, it works only with GMail.
When I use Fetch method with MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure it returns TextBody = null.
Does it work correctly only with GMail or I must fix some server settings?

**IMAP.log:**

```
Connected to imaps://mail.totalware.gr:993/
S: * OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+ AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN] Dovecot ready.
C: A00000000 AUTHENTICATE PLAIN AGZvc3Rpcm9wb3Vsb3NAdG90YWx3YXJlLmdyAEAhZm9zdGlyb3BvdWxvc0Ah
S: A00000000 OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE SORT SORT=DISPLAY THREAD=REFERENCES THREAD=REFS THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT MULTIAPPEND URL-PARTIAL CATENATE UNSELECT CHILDREN NAMESPACE UIDPLUS LIST-EXTENDED I18NLEVEL=1 CONDSTORE QRESYNC ESEARCH ESORT SEARCHRES WITHIN CONTEXT=SEARCH LIST-STATUS BINARY MOVE SNIPPET=FUZZY PREVIEW=FUZZY STATUS=SIZE NAMESPACE LITERAL+ NOTIFY SPECIAL-USE COMPRESS=DEFLATE QUOTA] Logged in
C: A00000001 NAMESPACE
S: * NAMESPACE (("INBOX." ".")) NIL NIL
S: A00000001 OK Namespace completed (0.001 + 0.000 secs).
C: A00000002 LIST "" "INBOX" RETURN (SUBSCRIBED CHILDREN)
S: * LIST (\HasChildren) "." INBOX
S: A00000002 OK List completed (0.017 + 0.000 + 0.016 secs).
C: A00000003 LIST (SPECIAL-USE) "" "*" RETURN (SUBSCRIBED CHILDREN)
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren \Archive) "." INBOX.Archive
S: * LIST (\Subscribed \HasNoChildren \Junk) "." INBOX.spam
S: * LIST (\Subscribed \HasNoChildren \UnMarked \Trash) "." INBOX.Trash
S: * LIST (\Subscribed \HasNoChildren \UnMarked \Sent) "." INBOX.Sent
S: * LIST (\Subscribed \HasNoChildren \Drafts) "." INBOX.Drafts
S: A00000003 OK List completed (0.001 + 0.000 secs).
C: A00000004 SELECT INBOX (CONDSTORE)
S: * FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft)
S: * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft \*)] Flags permitted.
S: * 21 EXISTS
S: * 0 RECENT
S: * OK [UIDVALIDITY 1513154986] UIDs valid
S: * OK [UIDNEXT 1634] Predicted next UID
S: * OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 3293] Highest
S: A00000004 OK [READ-WRITE] Select completed (0.002 + 0.000 + 0.001 secs).
C: A00000005 UID SEARCH RETURN () UNSEEN
S: * ESEARCH (TAG "A00000005") UID
S: A00000005 OK Search completed (0.001 + 0.000 secs).
C: A00000006 LOGOUT
S: * BYE Logging out
S: A00000006 OK Logout completed (0.001 + 0.000 secs).
```

Comment: What commands are sent and what are the server's responses? And are you really using the right mailbox?

Comment: And what software is the server running?  Some servers have really terrible `SEARCH` implementations, though I would hope they would at least support `UNSEEN`

Comment: I am surprised that UNSEEN doesn't work. If this was an issue with a string-matching criteria for the headers or body, that would not surprise me at all. Inbox.AddFlags() not working highly suggests he is using a read-only mailbox (or used EXAMINE instead of SELECT).

Comment: @Tasos Please paste the IMAP protocol logs so that we can figure out the issue. To get the logs, you can use `new ImapClient (new ProtocolLogger ("imap.log"))` to make the ImapClient save the IMAP protocol requests and responses to a file called "imap.log".

Comment: It turns out that some IMAP servers did not implement rfc4731 correctly. Namely, they do not treat `RETURN ()` as equivalent to `RETURN (ALL)`. MailKit 2.11.1 will be more explicit and use `RETURN (ALL)` to work around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to the log, the reason that MailKit's `Search(SearchQuery.Unseed)` returns no results is because your IMAP server is returning 0 matches.

It turns out that some IMAP servers did not implement rfc4731 correctly. Namely, they do not treat `RETURN ()` as equivalent to `RETURN (ALL)`. MailKit 2.11.1 will be more explicit and use `RETURN (ALL)` to work around this issue.